# eBay API to download user listing (eBay API user guide / step by step guide)

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am new to the eBay API and currently developing in PHP, I have managed to use GetItem to import details of an order based on the Item ID to my website's database. But What I want to do now is to link a users account to my website and import their listings to my database. I have put the code I used for GetItem (below) but now I am stuck and I don't know what to use, GetAccount, GetUser or GetSellerList to:

**First:** have my user redirected from my website to eBay to authorize my application to access his/her listings.

**Second:** Import that listing (an echo would be enough for now) to my website.

This is my code for GetItem:

```
     require_once('keys.php');
     require_once('eBaySession.php');

    if(isset($_POST['Id']))
    {
        //Get the ItemID inputted
        $id = $_POST['Id'];


        //SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
        //SiteID = 0  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
        //SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
        $siteID = 101;
        //the call being made:
        $verb = 'GetItem';

        ///Build the request Xml string
        $requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";;
        $requestXmlBody .= "<ItemID>$id</ItemID>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '</GetItemRequest>';

        //Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
        $session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);

        //send the request and get response
        $responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
        if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
            die('<P>Error sending request');

        //Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
        $responseDoc = new DomDocument();
        $responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


        //get any error nodes
        $errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');

        //if there are error nodes
        if($errors->length > 0)
        {
            echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
            //display each error
            //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
            $code = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
            $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
            $longMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');
            //Display code and shortmessage
            echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
            //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
            if(count($longMsg) > 0)
                echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

        }

        else //no errors
        {
            //get the nodes needed
            $titleNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Title');
            $primaryCategoryNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('PrimaryCategory');
            $categoryNode = $primaryCategoryNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('CategoryName');
            $listingDetailsNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('ListingDetails');
            $startedNode = $listingDetailsNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('StartTime');
            $endsNode = $listingDetailsNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('EndTime');

            $ShippingPackageDetailsNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('ShippingPackageDetails');
            if ($ShippingPackageDetailsNode->length > 0) {
                $packageDepthNode = $ShippingPackageDetailsNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('PackageDepth');
                $DepthUnit = $packageDepthNode->item(0)->getAttribute('unit');
                $packageLengthNode = $ShippingPackageDetailsNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('PackageLength');
                $LengthUnit = $packageLengthNode->item(0)->getAttribute('unit');
                $packageWidthNode = $ShippingPackageDetailsNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('PackageWidth');
                $WidthUnit = $packageWidthNode->item(0)->getAttribute('unit');
            }

            $sellingStatusNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('SellingStatus');
            $currentPriceNode = $sellingStatusNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('CurrentPrice');
            $currency = $currentPriceNode->item(0)->getAttribute('currencyID');
            $startPriceNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('StartPrice');
            $buyItNowPriceNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('BuyItNowPrice');
            $bidCountNode = $sellingStatusNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('BidCount');

            $sellerNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Seller');

            //Display the details
            echo '<P><B>', $titleNode->item(0)->nodeValue, " ($id)</B>";
            echo '<BR>Category: ', $categoryNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo '<BR>Started: ', $startedNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo '<BR>Ends: ', $endsNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

            if ($ShippingPackageDetailsNode->length > 0) {
                echo "<BR>Package Length: ", $packageLengthNode->item(0)->nodeValue, ' '.$LengthUnit.'';
                echo "<BR>Package Width: ", $packageWidthNode->item(0)->nodeValue, ' '.$WidthUnit.'';
                echo "<BR>Package Depth: ", $packageDepthNode->item(0)->nodeValue, ' '.$DepthUnit.'';
            }

            echo "<P>Current Price: ", $currentPriceNode->item(0)->nodeValue, $currency;
            echo "<BR>Start Price: ", $startPriceNode->item(0)->nodeValue, $currency;
            echo "<BR>BuyItNow Price: ", $buyItNowPriceNode->item(0)->nodeValue, $currency;
            echo "<BR>Bid Count: ", $bidCountNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

            //Display seller detail if present
            if($sellerNode->length > 0)
            {
                echo '<P><B>Seller</B>';
                $userIDNode = $sellerNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('UserID');
                $scoreNode = $sellerNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('FeedbackScore');
                $regDateNode = $sellerNode->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('RegistrationDate');

                echo '<BR>UserID: ', $userIDNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
                echo '<BR>Feedback Score: ', $scoreNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
                echo '<BR>Registration Date: ', $regDateNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**After reading a lot of poor documentation on eBay about it's API and getting crazy! I took matters in to my own hands and made a step by step guide about the API and figured out a way to do this. Which I will try to explain as simple as possible. (Using PHP)**

**What we will do:**

1. Create an application
2. Get a Session ID for our user from eBay
3. Connect to eBay using Session ID
4. User grants access to our application to link to his user account
   (using Session ID)
5. User Token generated
6. Our website receives User Token for future uses (to access user data
   on eBay)

**First**
You would need two PHP files called: keys.php and eBaySession.php which are found in eBay's PHP SDK which is located in eBay's Developers website Documentations. (**https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/sdks**)

**Second**
You will include these two files in a new PHP file which will also hold the user interface.

**Third**
You will create an account on eBay's Developers website and create a new application.

**Fourth**
You will obtain sandbox and production keys for your application using your developers account. Then you will generate a sandbox user and obtain a user token. (**via My Account Page**)

It could be a bit hard to find yourself around on eBay's Developers website but you will find the hang of it eventually.

**Fifth**
You will insert the DEV, APP, CERT and UserToken of your application in the keys.php file (both for production and sand-box modes)

**Sixth**
You would require a RuName, which is also located in the My Account Page (**Manage Your RuNames**).

**Seventh**
You will now insert the RuName in your keys.php file as a new parameter:

```
$RuName = 'your RuName key';
```

So our **keys.php** will look like this:

```
<?php
    //show all errors - useful whilst developing
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // these keys can be obtained by registering at http://developer.ebay.com

    $production         = true;   // toggle to true if going against production
    $compatabilityLevel = 551;    // eBay API version

    if ($production) {
        $devID = 'production dev id';   // these prod keys are different from sandbox keys
        $appID = 'production app id';
        $certID = 'production cert id';
        $RuName = 'production RuName';
        //set the Server to use (Sandbox or Production)
        $serverUrl = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';      // server URL different for prod and sandbox
        //the token representing the eBay user to assign the call with
        $userToken = 'production user token';
    } else {
        // sandbox (test) environment
        $devID = 'sandbox dev id';   // these prod keys are different from sandbox keys
        $appID = 'sandbox app id';
        $certID = 'sandbox cert id';
        //set the Server to use (Sandbox or Production)
        $serverUrl = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
        // the token representing the eBay user to assign the call with
        // this token is a long string - don't insert new lines - different from prod token
        $userToken = 'sandbox user token';
    }


?>
```

**Eight**
Now we will build our first page that has some output for the user as below:

```
<?php require_once('keys.php') ?>
<?php require_once('eBaySession.php') ?>
<?php

        session_start();
        //SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
        //SiteID = 0  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
        //SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
        $siteID = 0;
        //the call being made:
        $verb = 'GetSessionID';

        ///Build the request Xml string
        $requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<RuName>'.$RuName.'</RuName>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '</GetSessionIDRequest>';

        //Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
        $session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);

        //send the request and get response
        $responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
        if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
            die('<P>Error sending request');

        //Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
        $responseDoc = new DomDocument();
        $responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


        //get any error nodes
        $errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');

        //if there are error nodes
        if($errors->length > 0)
        {
            echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
            //display each error
            //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
            $code = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
            $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
            $longMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');
            //Display code and shortmessage
            echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
            //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
            if(count($longMsg) > 0)
                echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

        }

        else //no errors
        {
            //get the nodes needed
            $sessionIDNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('SessionID');
            //Display the details
            $sessionID = $sessionIDNode->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $_SESSION['eBaySession'] = $sessionID;

        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>Get eBay User Items</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="GetItem.php" method="post">
    <h2>Testing eBay Connection Plugin</h2>
    <h3>Linking User Account to our website</h3>
    <p>Session ID: <?php echo $_SESSION['eBaySession']; ?></p>
    <BR><a href="https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&RuName=<?php echo $RuName; ?>&SessID=<?php echo $sessionID; ?>">Click Here To Link Your Ebay Account To Our Website</a>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This new PHP page will receive a Session ID from eBay using `$verb = 'GetSessionID';` so when we click the "Link Your Ebay Account" button the user is sent to this URL:

```
https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&RuName=<?php echo $RuName; ?>&SessID=<?php echo $sessionID; ?>
```

**Which contains your RuName and Session ID.**

**Ninth**
User will login to eBay, grant access to your application and sent back to your website. Now we will use the same Session ID in the previous part to receive the User Token (since we have access to the user's account now) using `$verb = 'FetchToken';`.

```
<?php require_once('keys.php') ?>
<?php require_once('eBaySession.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>Get eBay User Items (Result)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <h2>Testing eBay Connection Plugin</h2>
    <h3>Receiving User Tocken</h3>
    <h4>With a User Tocken ID we can import user data to our website.</h4>

    <?php

            session_start();
            //SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
            //SiteID = 0  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
            //SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
            $siteID = 0;
            //the call being made:
            $verb = 'FetchToken';

            ///Build the request Xml string
            $requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
            $requestXmlBody .= '<FetchTokenRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
            $requestXmlBody .= '<SessionID>'.$_SESSION["eBaySession"].'</SessionID>';
            $requestXmlBody .= '</FetchTokenRequest>';

            //Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
            $session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);

            //send the request and get response
            $responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
            if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
                die('<P>Error sending request');

            //Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
            $responseDoc = new DomDocument();
            $responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


            //get any error nodes
            $errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');

            //if there are error nodes
            if($errors->length > 0)
            {
                echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
                //display each error
                //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
                $code = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
                $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
                $longMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');
                //Display code and shortmessage
                echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
                //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
                echo '<BR/>User Session ID: '.$_COOKIE["eBaySession"].'';
                if(count($longMsg) > 0)
                    echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

            }

            else //no errors
            {
                //get the nodes needed
                $eBayAuthTokenNode = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('eBayAuthToken');

                //Display the details
                echo '<BR/>User Session ID: '.$_SESSION["eBaySession"].'';
                echo '<BR/><BR/>User Token: '.$eBayAuthTokenNode->item(0)->nodeValue.'';

            }
    ?>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

And there you go you have access and a token. **But make sure you host this on a HTTPS URL since eBay only accepts these function through a secure connection (SSL). Otherwise you will have difficulty running this code.**

**I will improve this answer eventually by receiving feedback.** I know it may confuse you a bit but I hope I could make it a better answer by time. I have also covered the GetItem function for eBay API in the question if you would need it.

Edit: Of course you can integrate cUrl and XML requests.

Comment: Since you used the ebay API @Hossein Jabbari can you please assist me, where can I find the secretID of the ebay API?

Comment: Hi,
Great answer but i'm stuck on 9th point.
How do i get back on my website.
Please advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use eBay's SDK.  Or those 2 PHP include files you gave. I went crazy as you did, and I made my own SDK file which really just does some XML work and cURL.  I'm under contract so I can't yet share my file, but it's only 170 lines of code and you can use the entire eBay APIs as follows

```
$ebay = new Ebay();
$ebay->call("ReviseItem",array(
    "ItemID"=>"1234"
));
```

So you should use this api test tool from ebay
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx

And then you can just pass whatever call you want and read the params.  They are shitty, but it doesn't get easier than this.

Again, I wish I could share my code, but I'm just letting you know that if you buckle down, you can write just a bit of cURL and XML conversion to 'literally' use the API free of SDK.

I've done the same for Amazon MWS apis and google docs apis. I hope to be able to share all this as soon as possible

Comment: Trust me, it kills me that I can't share it yet.  I'm under NDA for the company.  I'm trying to finagle a way into this being beneficial to share.

Answer (score 0):

@Hossein Jabbari solution works. So basically you will need to download ebaysession.php file and include it with your app. It will handle all of the curl/xml part for you.

Plug-in all of your app details into the keys.php file. Then, when you make a redirect url name, your auth accepted URL should be the second php file which has the fetchToken function. Since you store the session ID from the first PHP file into session, retrieving it should be easy.

And then, go to the first PHP file to click on the Sign in URL. Then, log yourself into production or sandbox site and as soon as you click ACCEPT, you will be redirected to second PHP page and then you will be able to see your token.